# Trouble calling JSON component inside loop (Google Scripts)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been writing an algorithm in scripts to fill in missing data from a google sheet from API retrieval. After successfully retrieving the JSON object containing the relevant data I try to call specific parts and when done staticly- not an issue at all! However, when I try to call the same part inside a loop it spits out an error EVEN though the logs are fine. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
var jsonEmpSuper = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlBase.concat(urlEmp).concat(jsonInternalId.id).concat(urlBank), options));
var jsonBusDeducs = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlBase.concat(urlDeduc), options));

Logger.log(jsonBusDeducs[1].name);             //works!

for (var j = 0;j <= 10; j++) {                 //"TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from undefined."

  Logger.log(j);                               //works!
  Logger.log(jsonBusDeducs[j].name);           //works!
  Logger.log(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue());  //works!

  if (jsonBusDeducs[j].name == sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()) {

    Logger.log('Yo, ive spotted a match!');    //works, correctly spots matches?!?!?!

    sheet.getRange(i,18).setValue(jsonBusDeducs[j].id);

  }
```

The variables dictating the url and api details are witheld for privacy ofc.

Comment: What is `jsonBusDeducs.length`?

Comment: What does `jsonEmpSuper` have to do with this? It's never used in the code.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I missed including that variable. On it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably accessing outside the array in your loop. Change the limit to `jsonBusDeducs.length`:

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonBusDeducs.length; j++)
```

And remember that you have to use `<`, not `<=`. Array indexes go from `0` to `length-1`.